# Hexagon shape with Image and text

Tags: html, css, svg

I use [this](https://codepen.io/ericornelissen/pen/vWbWKv) for draw hexagon , i add svg to it.

I want to add image and text in new line.

I add this style

```css
 .hexagon > span {
           display: inline-block;
           transition: var(--hex-transition);
      }
```

```html
   <div class="hexagon color-angular">
     <svg aria-labelledby="simpleicons-angular-icon" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <title id="simpleicons-angular-icon">Angular icon</title>
      <path d="M9.93 12.645h4.134L11.996 7.74"/>
      <path d="M11.996.009L.686 3.988l1.725 14.76 9.585 5.243 9.588-5.238L23.308 3.99 11.996.01zm7.058 18.297h-2.636l-1.42-3.501H8.995l-1.42 3.501H4.937l7.06-15.648 7.057 15.648z"/>
     </svg>
     <span>Kitchen</span>
    </div>
```

But show text inside of image

Comment: can you explain a little bit more. where do you want to show your text?

Comment: I want to show The text below of svg. when i add span after svg, show it next to each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codepen.io/tushgraph/pen/agyrdO

```
.blokedtext{position:absolute; bottom:-12px; z-index:100; color:#000; font-family:arial; font-size:0.8em;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.hexagon>span {
  transition: var(--hex-transition);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon color-angular">
  <svg aria-labelledby="simpleicons-angular-icon" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title id="simpleicons-angular-icon">Angular icon</title><path d="M9.93 12.645h4.134L11.996 7.74"/><path d="M11.996.009L.686 3.988l1.725 14.76 9.585 5.243 9.588-5.238L23.308 3.99 11.996.01zm7.058 18.297h-2.636l-1.42-3.501H8.995l-1.42 3.501H4.937l7.06-15.648 7.057 15.648z"/>
 <text x="10" y="20" text-anchor="" fill="white" font-size="1">Kitchen</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to have `display: inline-block` in your span since it is overridden by the `display:flex;` :)

Comment: @Irin, thanks, but dont show text in new line, it is show inside svg.

Comment: check it now @ar.gorgin